# How can I order the rows inside a table by a column (but not the `SELECT`'s response)?

Tags: sql, sorting, sqlite, multiple-columns

For example, I want to order a table like this

```
Foo | Bar
---------
 1  |  a
 5  |  d
 2  |  c
 1  |  b
 2  |  a
```

to this:

```
Foo | Bar
---------
 1  |  a
 1  |  b
 2  |  a
 2  |  c
 5  |  d
```

(ordered by Foo column)

That's because I only want to select the Bars that have a given Foo, and if it's already ordered I guess they will be faster to select because I won't have to use `ORDER BY`.

And if it's possible, once sorting by columns Foo, I want to sort the rows which have the same Foo by Bar column.

Of course, if I `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to table, it should remain ordered.

Comment: The **only** way to get an ordered result set is to use an `order by` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, tables are inherently unordered.  This is a very important characteristic of databases.  For instance, you can delete a row in the middle of a table, and when a new row is inserted, it uses up the space occupied by the deleted row.  This is more efficient that just appending rows to the end of the data.

In other words, the `order by` clause is used basically for output purposes only.  Okay, I can think of two other situations . . . with `limit` (or a related clause) and with window functions (which SQLite does not support).

In any case, ordering the data also would not matter for a query such as this:

```
select bar
from t
where foo = $FOO
```

The SQL engine does not "know" that the table is ordered.  So, it will start at the beginning of the table and do the comparison for each row.

The way to make this more efficient is by building an index on `foo`.  Then you will be able to get the efficiencies that you want.

Comment: And how can I build an index?

Comment: You can use a create index query and run it.  Or your database client might have a visual way of doing it.

Comment: @Oriol . . . Here is the documentation on the command http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html.  The statement is something like `create index t_foo on t(foo);`.